# extend jquery draggable/droppable to support on iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I've been using JQuery draggable/droppables in my application from last 1 year. Now, the application needs to be supported over iPad and iPhones.

Known, above JQuery won't support drag/drop over iPads...

I'm looking for a some JQuery plugin or so which I can connect to my existing JQuery codes for drag/drop over iPad.

After googling, I found some alternate ways like, JQTouch, jquerymobile etc.. But, it looks I would then need to do massive changes (or, write a complete drag/drop things from scratch) in my application :(

My application is very heavy and hence looking for some quick/easy way to connect my existing JQuery solution into iPad touch events etc....

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This project will allow you to use jQuery UI on the iPad:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/

Comment: Hi jturnbull, Thanks for your inputs! I've checked this solution, but then ran into problems like, after implementing this, mouseout events of the elements other than the draggable objects in the same page stops working. As a result, some DIVs that should get disappear when user taps on the page except that element still remain visible. One other problem is, in current app, dragclone's position is calculated manually while dragging. After implementing this, droppables do not activate in iPad.I simply referenced the js file provided in solution in the html page, nothing else. Is that enough?

Comment: Yeah, just adding the js file enabled jQuery UI draggables for me.I got the latest js file from the svn, which may make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch

this will work with draggable.. dont even need to change your code when using draggable!